# RewriteRule Appending Query for Existing Directories

Tags: model-view-controller, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm implementing an MVC pattern for my new PHP site with a URL structure like the following:

```
example.com/module/controller/action?params=...
```

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) portal.php?mvc=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The rules are working mostly right, however, if I have a directory in the public space with the same name as a module, it appends `?mvc=[directory name]` to the end of the URL if there is no trailing slash.

For example:
`example.loc/index` turns into `example.loc/index/?mvc=index`
but `example.loc/index/` stays the same.

How can I make it so that if the user types in `example.loc/index` it has the same behavior as if they had included the ending slash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because mod_dir's [`DirectorySlash` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) is interfering with your rewrites. Both mod_dir and mod_rewrite sit in the same URL-file mapping pipeline, and they're both going to do their thing no matter what the other module is doing. So when mod_dir thinks a request is for a directory, and there's a missing trailing slash, then it's going to flag the URL to be redirected, but the URL continues down the processing pipeline where mod_rewrite does its thing to the URI. At the end of the line, both modules modified the URI **and** the URI was flagged to a 301 redirect, so the response to the browser is to redirect to the new URI (which has been mangled).

**Solution:**  You need to either handle the trailing slash within mod_rewrite or simply turn off `DirectorySlash` (although you should note the information disclosure security warning). You can handle the trailing slash in mod_rewrite like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to add that *right under the `RewriteEngine on` line. You need this applied before any MVC routing happens.

Comment: I used the Rewrite condition and rule and it seems to be working perfectly! Google Chrome was remembering my other URIs, though, and that was confusing me for a bit. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f directive ?
I guess Apache will treat example.loc/index/ as a folder in the file system rather than a file.

Comment: I need the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` so I can either have a request like `example.com/module/controller/action?params=...` and send it to the portal.php or have `example.com/module/img/picture.jpg` and serve the correct file.